# Numpy - removing rows from one array using rows of another one

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds

I have a two arrays, which contain large datasets - point clouds.
The first array is build from more than three columns, where first three are XYZ coordinates and the rest of columns contain additional informations. One row is basically one point with given cooridnates and additional parametres - not important at this stage.

The second array contain only three - XYZ - columns.

From the first array I would like to remove all rows (points) which XYZ coorindates overlap within given buffor with any of the row (point) from the second array.

For example here is the first array:

```
15.0 23.0 35.5 222 211 254
13.0 33.0 34.5 223 232 244
15.0 23.0 35.5 226 211 253
15.4 22.1 32.5 122 231 252
14.1 24.4 36.5 242 212 251
15.0 23.4 55.5 223 211 253
15.0 23.5 45.5 222 211 254
```

Here is the second one:

```
15.0 23.1 35.6
13.1 33.1 34.4
15.5 23.1 35.8
15.4 22.1 32.9
14.1 24.8 36.5
15.5 23.4 55.9
15.9 23.5 45.5
```

And my given buffer is 0.1. As a result I would like to obtain the following array:

```
15.0 23.0 35.5 226 211 253
15.4 22.1 32.5 122 231 252
14.1 24.4 36.5 242 212 251
15.0 23.4 55.5 223 211 253
15.0 23.5 45.5 222 211 254
```

What is the best way to implement this task using numpy?

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```py
def filter(arr1, arr2, threshold):
  return arr1[np.linalg.norm(arr1[:,:3] - arr2, axis=1) < threshold]
```